# CSS Menu Overflow?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a css menu, pretty standard functionality. I have implemented it within a Netsuite site im working on.

The menu is visible here:

http://www.gardensandhomesdirect.co.uk

Its the one just under the header.

Ive been trying to get the only part of the menu with dropdowns to come left instead of right when hovered so that it is not being 'hidden' underneath the wrapper.

What is the best way to get this menu showing correctly? I there a way i can get it hover over the top of everything else instead of underneath like now?

Any help appreciated.

-Wayne

Comment: FWIW you should really consider changing the text of the menu links from white to a dark color. There is little contrast as is and it's pretty tough to read them agains the light blue background (you could also change the bg to a dark color if you want to keep the white text).

Comment: hi JAG2007,

Thank you for the input. At the moment, we have no test environment for our sites so almost every change has to be done in a live situation which isnt ideal.

Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `overflow: visible` on `#outerwrapper` if you want to show anything outside that div.

Alin

Comment: Unbelievable, I completely negated to look at that.

Thank you Alin, working perfect now !! :)